# Serialize delegate in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, delegates

I have 3 models in Rails: User, UserProfile and Post

Something like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :post_type
  belongs_to :user

  delegate :fullname, :to => :user, :prefix => "author"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_one :user_info
  delegate :fullname, :to => :user_info
end

class UserInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :avatar, :fullname, :birthday, :nickname, :gender, :about

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now I use knockout to manage posts at client-side so I have to make my object to json using posts.to_json. These JSON objects don't have attributes fullname. I tried with user.to_json, and these objects don't have that attribute either. So how can I make the delegate serialize to JSON?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since fullname is a virtual attribute in the sense:

**Rails 2:**

```
posts.to_json(:method => %w(fullname))
user.to_json(:method => %w(fullname))
```

**Rails 3:**

```
posts.to_json(:methods => %w(fullname))
user.to_json(:methods => %w(fullname))
```